# Prophet Musa request to see/meet Allah SWT

Tags: prophet-musa

In this verse, https://quran.com/7/143, Prophet Musa requested Allah SWT to reveal Himself to him so that he can see Allah.
Later this ayat tells that when Allah came up on mountain Sinai at the appointed time, it was crumbled to dust and His presence was so strong (I have been told that there was too much bright light) that Prophet Musa fell unconscious and could not see him.
My question is that if Allah SWT is all strong and all supreme, He could have simply revealed Himself in a way that could have been perceptible by Prophet Musa. Allah SWT could have controlled the crumbling of the mountains and could have prevented the unconsciousness of Prophet Musa.

In the next verse, https://quran.com/7/144, Allah SWT mentioned that He has favored Prophet Musa above all. To quote "...he(Prophet Musa) has already been favored by Allah over the people of his time through prophethood and direct communication with the Almighty." This shows the love of Allah for Prophet Musa.

If Prophet Musa was so dear and close to Allah SWT, then why didn't He fulfill the request of Prophet Musa if He is all supreme? Why didn't Allah reveal Himself to one of his dearest Prophets on his request?

Answer (score 1):

Being All Majestic and All Powerful is part of what Allah *is*. If He revealed Himself in a way that *wasn't* All Majestic and All Powerful, then how could you say that He even revealed Himself at all?

Comment: If you read my description, I have myself said that Allah SWT didn't reveal Himself in a way perceptible to Prophet Musa.